# Generators and relations of non-associative algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, monoidal-categories

Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a non-strict tensor category with associator $a$ and that $A$ is an algebra object in this category. Thus $(A, \mu)$ satisfies the following diagram.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
(A\otimes A)\otimes A @>{a_{A,A,A}}>> A\otimes (A\otimes A) @>{1\otimes\mu}>> A\otimes A \\
@V{\mu\otimes 1}VV   @. @VV{\mu}V \\
A\otimes A @>>{\mu}> A @= A
\end{CD}

Assume for simplicity that $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of vector spaces with some associator. Can we talk about generators and relations for $A$? If you ignore the category part, $(A,\mu)$ is a non-associative algebra, can we talk about generators and relations for non-associative algebras?

If the answer is yes, that would be awesome, but it doesn't solve my problem, because I have a certain object $A$ in a non-strict category $\mathcal{C}$ and a morphism $\mu:A\otimes A\rightarrow A$ and I want to show that $(A,\mu)$ is an algebra object by showing that it satisfies the diagram above. However checking this for all elements of $A$ seems to be difficult, but I feel $A$ is in some sense still generated by certain elements, so probably I don't need to check it for all elements.

Comment: The problem I can see with what you are trying to do is the fact that you are working in a purely categorical manner (which is good!), but generators and relations of an algebra are something inherent to the object. Therefore, the two approaches live in different worlds, in some sense.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: I can imagine that. I was able to show that in my case $A$ was indeed an algebra object in a certain non-strict category but I don't have to many methods to do this. If you consider Lie algebras, they are also non-associative algebras (with the Jacobi identity taking the role of some associativity condition). For Lie algebras it's clear what generators and relations are, but in my particular example it's not immediately clear to me. Anyways, the question is pretty vague, I don not expect a clear answer, but techniques in various cases might help.